# Using jsoncpp dll to build another dll project : link time issues

Tags: c++, dll, linker, jsoncpp

I am using json-cpp lib to build another dll project in Visual studio  2008.

Linker settings :
output file is a dll

Input tab : I have added the json cpp lib in additional dependencies

[image: general tab]
[image: manifest tab]
[image: system tab]
[image: optimization tab]
[image: Advanced tab]
I get the following unresolved symbols given below
Also tried defining JSON_DLL to JSON_API, but it didnt work.
If there is a fix for this problem?

```
.. error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: bool cdecl Json::ValueIteratorBase::isEqual(class Json::ValueIteratorBase const &)const " (?isEqual@ValueIteratorBase@Json@@IEBA_NAEBV12@@Z)
.. error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: void cdecl Json::ValueIteratorBase::increment(void)" (?increment@ValueIteratorBase@Json@@IEAAXXZ)
.. error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: class Json::Value & cdecl Json::ValueIteratorBase::deref(void)const " (?deref@ValueIteratorBase@Json@@IEBAAEAVValue@2@XZ)
.. error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: cdecl Json::ValueIterator::ValueIterator(class Json::ValueIterator const &)" (??0ValueIterator@Json@@QEAA@AEBV01@@Z)
.. error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class _STL::basic_string,class _STL::allocator > cdecl Json::FastWriter::write(class Json::Value const &)" (?write@FastWriter@Json@@UEAA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@_STL@@@_STL@@AEBVValue@2@@Z)
.. error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class _STL::basic_string,class _STL::allocator > cdecl Json::Value::asString(void)const " (?asString@Value@Json@@QEBA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@_STL@@@_STL@@XZ)
.. error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class Json::Value cdecl Json::ValueIteratorBase::key(void)const " (?key@ValueIteratorBase@Json@@QEBA?AVValue@2@XZ)
.. error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class Json::Value & cdecl Json::Value::operator" (??AValue@Json@@QEAAAEAV01@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@_STL@@@_STL@@@Z)
.. error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class Json::Value & cdecl Json::Value::operator" (??AValue@Json@@QEAAAEAV01@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@_STL@@@_STL@@@Z)
.. error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: bool cdecl Json::Reader::parse(class _STL::basic_string,class _STL::allocator > const &,class Json::Value &,bool)" (?parse@Reader@Json@@QEAA_NAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@_STL@@@_STL@@AEAVValue@2@_N@Z)
```

Comment: It would be useful if you __at least__ provided some information about your linked settings. Currently there's no way to help you.

Comment: Hi, Paweł Stawarz, added the linker settings.

Comment: Check here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636(v=vs.90).aspx

If you got a *.lib file, you can set it in Project->settings->configuration properties->linker->input